# Javascript bug in Chrome and Opera

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

While developing some JavaScript code for browser I encountered weird bug in Chrome:

```
var element = document.getElementById('someId');
element.style.customProp = 'my property';

element.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log(element.style.customProp);
}, false);
```

On click console prints 'undefined', but when I change code to:

```
var element = document.getElementById('someId');
element.style.customProp = 'my property';
var a = element.style;

element.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log(element.style.customProp);
}, false);
```

console prints 'my property'.

First version of the code works as expected in Firefox and Internet Explorer. It doesn't in Chrome and Opera. For me it's clearly a bug, but maybe I'm missing something. Is this really a bug or what am I missing?

Comment: So the only difference is that you're saving a reference in that "a" variable to the "style" object?

Comment: My guess is that Webkit browsers are designed not to you to set just any property on the style object. Don't know why the second allows you to though.

Comment: If I set a random property on a "style" object from the Chrome console, it seems to work just fine.

Comment: Running `document.body.style.thisdoesntexist='asdfdf';console.log(document.body.style.thisdoesntexist)` in the console prints undefined.

Comment: Seems like a bug. When I tried to reproduce, it worked fine unless I had a border-radius set.

Comment: When trying to reproduce this bug using JSfiddle, trick with assigning style to some variable doesn't seem to work. But it works when I run script 'directly', loading it within html file.

Answer (score 0):

**Seems Like A WebKit Bug**
See [Fiddle 1](http://jsfiddle.net/6tp8a/2/) (works) vs. [Fiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/6tp8a/3/) (doesn't)

Some properties seem to block custom style properties in Chrome. This test shows border-radius, but others might.

It didn't seem to matter whether I used:

```
var element = document.getElementById('someId');
element.style.customProp = 'my property';

element.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log(element.style.customProp);
}, false);
```

or:

```
var element = document.getElementById('someId');
element.style.customProp = 'my property';
var a = element.style;

element.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log(element.style.customProp);
}, false);
```

For what it's worth I saw the error on Chrome 31. Not sure what other versions might be affected.

Submitted Report [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=321351&thanks=321351&ts=1384902679)

Comment: Both fiddles doesn't seem to work. In first after you re-run it, it acts exactly like second one.
Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Lyb3u/
It will work fine when you load the page, but re-run it and check behaviour. Onload alert works fine, but onclick doesn't.

Comment: I checked your fiddles again and they both act exactly like mine. They work fine when you load the page (alert 'my property' on click), but after re-run they start to act like in described bug (alert 'undefined').
Though you can reproduce this bug on JSfiddle, solution with assigning style to variable doesn't work there. For this you need to fire script from html page.

Comment: feel free to add more the the linked bug report. Not much more I can do. :)

Answer (score 0):

`element.style` is an instance of `CSSStyleDeclaration`, which means it’s a *host object*, not a native javascript object.

The ECMAScript specification states that host objects are not subject to the same rules as native objects, so I wouldn’t expect this to be defined as a "bug" (even though I never could replicate it).